# Please explain detailed steps to uninstall STS4 from Ubuntu 20.04 completely with all the files related to it

Tags: spring-boot

```
open STS
Go to Help -> About Spring Tool Suite
Click on installation details
Check installed software
Click on Spring tool suite under installed software
Click Uninstall.
```

I followed these steps to uninstall the STS4 in Ubuntu 20.04. But these steps do not make sure that all the configs related to STS4 are removed form my computer. I need a step by step guide to uninstall STS4 through commandline in such a way that there is nothing related to the software stays in my computer

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.